# Python turtle graphics malfunction on a Mac running OSX 10.6

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit, turtle-graphics

This is the result when I attempt to run Python turtle graphics on my Mac. 
Has anyone else seen this.  Are there suggestions for fixing this problem. Thanks
in advance!

```
$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Aug  2 2010, 20:10:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 114, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "/Users/morrison/copy.py", line 3, in <module>
    Interface summary:
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your current directory `/Users/morrison/` when you run this?

If so, the problem is that the interpreter's current working directory is being used for looking up python modules at runtime in addition to the standard locations. You have a file `copy.py` in this directory and it is being imported when the standard library `copy` module is what was intended by the `turtle` module.

This happens because when you run the python interpreter interactively, it will add the current working directory to the front of `sys.path` automatically. (There's a likewise effect if you were trying to run a script in this dir from a different directory - the script's directory would be added to the front of `sys.path`.)

The easiest way around this is to just rename `copy.py` to `mycopy.py` (and don't forget to remove `copy.pyc` in that dir).

Comment: Also be aware that `turtle` in Python uses Python's `Tkinter` graphics module which in turn relies on `Tcl/Tk`.  The Apple-supplied `Tcl/Tk` 8.5 released with OS X 10.6 has serious problems and you may find that they will cause Python `Tkinter` programs to hang or crash.  The recommendations here (http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) for IDLE apply as well to `turtle` usage.  I recommend installing the latest 64-/32-bit Python 2.7.x release from python.org (http://www.python.org/download/) along with the latest ActiveState Tcl/Tk 8.5 (http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads)

Comment: I had removed the .py file but not the .pyc file.  Thanks for the rescue from this headache!  All is as it should be.